# Get X screen layout information

Tags: monitors, x-server

I've been having trouble finding an answer on duckduckgo and this forum.

Here is my situation:
I have a monitor connected via HDMI cable to my laptop and I set it up with

`xrandr --output HDMI-1 --right-of eDP-1`

My question is simple: The information that my external HDMI monitor is to the right of my laptop has to be saved somewhere in a file or something, right?

How can I get that information?

I searched the *Xorg.log* for information but I couldn't find any, and
`xrandr --verbose` is of no help either.

Comment: `xrandr --listmonitors` might be helpful.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Changes made by `xrandr` are not saved somewhere. If you want to be applied everytime you boot, you can use X.org files to re-execute the command. Is that your goal?

Comment: xrandr --listmonitors is actually the solution, thanks!
It's a little bit hidden in the output but it's there!

Interestingly, the manpage never mentions a --listmonitors option (OpenSUSE Leap 15.1) ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--listmonitors` option. Example output:

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 2
 0: +DP1 1920/520x1200/320+1920+0  DP1
 1: +HDMI3 1920/520x1200/320+0+0  HDMI3
```

--listmonitors option has been added to xrandr manpage in [this
commit](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xrandr/-/commit/5e95248b5bab1254ecedffb6cb681b0ee06c0f29) in February 2018.